# How to use sbt to specify dependsOn other module with different scala version?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a multiple module projects in scala. Module A, B, C. B --dependsOn--> A and C --dependsOn--> A too. The module A && C is compiled by scala 2.11 while module B has to be compiled by scala 2.10 since there is a dependency library only with scala 2.10. How to use sbt to specify module B dependsOn module A?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. Period. Either switch A and C to compile with Scala 2.10 as well, or if the source of 2.10-only library is available, update it to 2.11.

Comment: That's say scala 2.10 project can NOT depends on scala 2.11 project, am I right? Since B can't be updated to 2.11, I have to use git submodule to include module A into project B and compile it with scala 2.10

Comment: You don't need git submodule, though it's a possible solution. Just cross-compile A with both 2.11 and 2.10 (see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html) and make it a `libraryDependency`.